# Using an EventBus to emit data to another component and using the emitted data in the component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Cutting straight to the point. I am emitting an event in component1 and listening for it in component2 below. My emits are coming through, because the payload is being displayed in my console. However, I am not capable of finding a way to use this newely recieved data and use it with the login default export below. Component1 is a child of Component2.

For example, I want to modify the prop: authInfo with the newely gotten payload.

component2:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import router from '../router'
import AuthenticationService from '@/services/AuthenticationService'
import { EventBus } from '../scripts/EventBus'

// Listen for event
EventBus.$on('UserLoggedOut', payload =>{
  console.log(payload)
});

export const login = {
  name: 'LoginView',
  props: {
    authInfo: false,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      langs: ['de', 'en'],
      username: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',
      repeatPassword: '',
      error1: false,
      error2: false
    };
  },
  methods: { ... }
}
```

Could anyone give me a pointer in the right direction? JavaScript is new land for me ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Listening for an event in component

...inside your component definition:

```js
created() {
  EventBus.$on('UserLoggedOut', payload => { ...do what your need - "this" is current component... 
  });
}
```

> For example, I want to modify the prop: authInfo with the newely gotten payload

This is little bit tricky. Props are [considered "input only" in Vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow). Common pattern is "props down, events up" - meaning parent component owns the data (in its own `data()`), passes the data by props down to a child component and if the child component wants to change this data, it emits an event which parent listens to and in the handler change its internal data - new value will flow by reactivity and prop into the child.

Comment: I've tried with created(), but it doesn't get called.

Comment: `created()` is called only when the component is created/rendered. Is your component rendered before your event is fired? If yes, it should receive the event....

Comment: Okay, my bad, I accidentally called it within methods. But it's part of the Vue life-cycle methods. Thanks man.